Restrict Hasura Console
I have a self-hosted Hasura installation. Right now Hasura Console in accessible via admin token you need to provide.
This approach is unfeasible for us because I can't give admin token to everyone, so I would like restrict console access to company users having certain LDAP groups.
How can I do that? As far as I understood hasura console works just with admin token.
In our company we use google apigee, so We're thinking about using an apigee proxy that performs some check and redirect to hasura console, is that feasible? In that case how can I pass the admin token from apigee?
Please, tell if I'm wrong and there is more straightforward way to achieve that.
Regards
I tried enabling jwt auth but this is just mean to be useful for API calls and not for Console access.

Assuming you have used the HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE flag, anyone can access the api explorer (GraphiQL console). They would still need to provide authentication to complete any queries or introspect the schema. They can use any acceptable header to do so. If they don't have an admin secret they can use a valid bearer token. Just add a "authorization" header and for the value, use "Bearer " as you would in any client. These users would have access to any resources their permission set grants them as long as the token remains valid.
